# Fastify Rewrite URL

Tags: node.js, http, fastify

How can I use Fastify’s rewriteUrl option for all requests with a path that starts with `/r/` and rewrite the url to `https://example.com/example`?

Comment: do you mean to forward the request to another domain?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon yes, I wish to rewrite the url to another domain

Comment: You need to use https://github.com/fastify/fastify-reply-from I will try to arrange a complete answer